# Getting javax.crypto/AEADBadTagException: Tag Mismatch! for AES GCM decryption

Tags: java, aes-gcm

We are trying to decrypt the data using AES GCM, But we getting below error

`byte[] decData = c.doFinal(dataBytes);` --- getting issue in this place

> javax.crypto/AEADBadTagException: Tag Mismatch!  at
> com.sun.crypto.provider.galoisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:620)

Is above issue is due to code or key or IV? Need help to resolve the same.

Guide us to resolve the problem

Below is the code, for decryption.

```
public static String decrypt(String encData, String aesKey, String iv) {
    byte[] dataBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encData);
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] ivVal = iv.getBytes("UTF-8");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstances("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, ivVal);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, AES), spec);
    byte[] decData = c.doFinal(dataBytes);
    return new String(decData, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: It could be the code, the IV, the key, or the ciphertext. Without complete and precise requirements, or the code that did the encryption, no guidance can be given. However, having an IV represented as a Java `String`, unless that string is a binary-preserving encoding like base64 or hex, is bad design and probably wrong.